# A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator

Tags: django-admin

i have tried to migrate all apps.it is successfully registered. but i am added another app (music) adding one model Album it will be migrate but when i am trying to register like

"admin.site.register(Album)"
there is problem will occur it running successfully but it shows error in browser

"A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator."

this project folder structure in this apps directory we have another folder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbeyN.png)

this is apps folder structure in this we music app when  i am trying to run it shows error above i mentioned error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T789N.png)

Comment: make `DEBUG=True` and provide the traceback. then we will able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

as Vinay Kumar above says, set DEBUG=True and provide the traceback. 
Also provide the code in app music/admin.py.